# Download link from firefox console

Tags: firefox, console

How do (or can) I download an URL from the firefox GCLI or javascript console?

Reason for asking: when logged into Jenkins, I often need to download a multiple of logfiles for analysis. Since I need to log in, I think, this is not possible with wget/curl etc.

*Bonus question: is this question more relevant in another stack exchange site?*

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified address structure of this log files. So, I expecting you are able to make loop generating log file address.

Check your FF settings:

- Downloads - set folder for downloads (unless you don't want to
  confirm every file save location)
- Pop-up policy (it's not necessary, you will se yellow stripe prompt)
- File association - set log filetype always download. (Settings -
  applications tab)

Now you can make loop in javascript which open new windows (tab - default FF settings) with  for every address from list. (Hint: `window.open('log_file_address')`)

Comment: But then I need to change my settings and change them back. I was hoping for something like window.save(filename)

Comment: Or if this site provided list of the links to log files, you can use some Firefox extensions which allow to select multiple links and open.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't any Javascript method for direct download due security reasons.

Comment: Thanks, Lluser. I am afraid that this answered the question.